# Unity cs1519 error with c# code

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have been developing a game within unity and i have encountered an error that i cannot seem to fix.

the error says 'error CS1519: Unexpected symbol 'public' in class, struct, or interface member declaration'[image]

here is the C# code. the error says it is in the line under the one that is highlighted. the public float speed, (as your can probably tell.) can i get an explaination of the error so i know how to fix it and a possible fix or this one,

Comment: i fixed it but i just created 10 more errors

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
public Boundary Boundary
```

should be:

```
public Boundary boundary;
```

since you're using a reference to boundary when setting the position property in the Rigidbody component at the bottom of that snippet.